# concurrently powering ten micro dc motors in a circuit

Tags: dc-motor

I have built a sort of small raspi controlled remote car with 12 tires using regular drone motors such as [these ones](https://www.amazon.de/ViaGasaFamido-RPM-50000-Hohlschale-Coreless-Quadcopter/dp/B07Z3XBPDS/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=3v%20drone%20motor&qid=1628187888&sr=8-5) and am using a raspberry pi and six [drv8833 motor drivers](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1628136664305&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to control them. The power source is a [60W AC adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083GG2H6R) that can be downregulated to 3.5V.
Initially the cirquit was barely able to run two motors concurrently with the provided power source alone. The leds of the DRV8833 all fluctuated and went black whenever more than two motors were running.

I connected ten 470mF 35V capacitors to the circuit (in parallel, the positive side connected to the v+ wire and the negative one to ground) and now I am able to run almost six of those motors at the same time. However, these capacitors are quite large and I don't want to add another ten or fifteen just to be able to get this device running the way it's supposed to be.

Right now the car is turned upside down and the motors are running without any resistance apart from the force required to get the motors to run.

The current limit for the DRV8833 is 2A, I am using two of those modules with each having two motors connected to them.

Here is what the setup roughly looks like:
[image]

Is there a better way to deal with the sudden burst of required amperage when firing up all motors at once? Right now I am using the capacitors as some sort of battery, is there something else that is more efficient that I could use in place of that?

Comment: Can't see any Pi relevance to the question.  The title bears no relationship to the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes - there are better ways. You may find some [useful ideas in this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=start+multiple+dc+motors+simultaneously&atb=v278-1&ia=web)

Answer (score 1):

(1) The root cause of trouble is that all motors start at the same time, each with a big in rush of current, usually several times of the steady current.

(2) There are basically 2 solutions: software and hardware.

(3) Using software, you can let Rpi/Pico start the motors sequentially, one after another, with a random delay of say, 10ms.

(4) Or if you wish all motors start at the same time, you can let Rpi start them all at a very low speed, by setting 1kHz PWM duty cycle, say, at 20% or even smaller.

(5) For hardware approach, you can get those cheap motor driver modules with a built in poly fuse, which limits the starting current in rush.